# loop through an array of object with handlebars.js

Tags: handlebars.js

I have a structure like this:

```
 obj: {
  array: [{
   string: 'hello'
  },
   string: 'tim'
  }]
}
```

how can i print all the string propery in an unordered list?

i'm trying with this but it doesn't print nothing

```
<ul>
{{#each array}}
<li>{{this string}}</li>
{{/each}}    
</ul>
```

Comment: Have a look on this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22696886/how-to-iterate-over-array-of-objects-in-handlebars. There is a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/yR7TZ/1/ as well. Looks very similar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code

```
<ul>
{{#each array}}
<li>{{this.string}}</li>
{{/each}}    
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

**TL;DR**: According to `each` helper code in the [docs](https://handlebarsjs.com/guide/block-helpers.html#simple-iterators), context is set to current item.

Second argument implicitly passed to helper is `options` object, that contains `fn` property. This property is a function [that behaves like a normal compiled Handlebars template](https://handlebarsjs.com/guide/block-helpers.html#basic-blocks) (containing what have been placed between `{{#each}}` and `{{/each}}`).
Helper iterates over the array and evaluate the template for each item. Concatenated result is returned.

So, you don't have to use `this`.

```html
<ul>
{{#each array}}
  <li>{{string}}</li>
{{/each}}    
</ul>
```

[Fiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/h8Leagrb/)