# Handlebars is not showing elements of objects inside an array

Tags: node.js, express, handlebars.js

My project code has been working perfectly fine 5 months ago. Now I am not getting why handlebars is not showing data in any list. I have checked backend, where I am getting array of categories and i can console.log elements of objects inside the array. Here is my backend code:

```
// shows category list
exports.categoryList = async( req, res )=> {
  var category = await Cat.find()
  var count = 1
  category.map( doc=> doc.count = count++  )
  console.log(category)
  console.log(category[0].name)
  res.render('parents/categoryList', { category })
}
```

Output of these console.log:

```
[ { subCategories: [],
    brands: [],
    enabled: false,
    discount: null,
    _id: 5e6f2a069894412b749e2fca,
    name: 'abcd',
    created: 2020-03-16T07:25:58.335Z,
    __v: 0 } ]
abcd
```

In handlebar I have tried printing category variable which I have passed from backend:

```
<p>{{category}}</p>

{{#each category}}

count: {{this.count}} <br>
id: {{this._id}}<br>

{{/each}}
```

Front-end output:

```
{ subCategories: [], brands: [], enabled: false, discount: null, _id: 5e6f2a069894412b749e2fca, name: 'abcd', created: 2020-03-16T07:25:58.335Z, __v: 0 }
count: 1
id:
```

As you can see the count variable what I have set in the backend code is not inside the category object but its printing while iterating through the category array. Could anyone tell me what's went wrong?

Answer (score 0):

**.map** will return array. If you save that array in some variable I believe it will work.

```
const updArr = category.map( doc=> {
  const newDoc = {}
  newDoc = doc;
  newDoc.count = count++
  return newDoc;
})
console.log(updArr) // check output here
res.render('parents/categoryList', { updArr })
```

On fronted try to console **this** object. I think this object is the response of your api that you are getting it from backend. And this.count is the count of your records.

Thanks

Comment: Not working. The updArr is showing [1,2,3,4,5] in console. But i had a query result in category, which is being overridden.

Comment: now I am getting query result objects with count...which is ok. But in the handlebars only count is showing but other object elements like name, _id are not showing. my problem is, in the given code, back and front both were working perfectly. i had  only fixed some vulnerabilities of that project. which might causing the problem.

Comment: just try console (this) on frontend and let me know what it is printing.

Comment: As I understand your code. You are getting object on frontend not the array. 
Try {{category._id}}

Comment: {{category._id}} with ur code shows nothing. with my code shows nothing. (i have more than one object in the array)

Comment: Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22696886/how-to-iterate-over-array-of-objects-in-handlebars