# Can't print element of array in handlebars template

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express-handlebars

I'm trying to print a list of products to one of my handlebar views and it won't let me print a specific property of one of the objects inside array I passed in.

store.js:

This is what I used to render the handlebars view:

```
res.render("products.handlebars", { products });
```

I logged "products" right before it got passed to the line above, it's an array of objects

and in the products.handlebars file:

this prints the entire array and all of the contents of the object inside the products.handlebars view

```
{{#each products}}
{{this}}
{{/each}}
```

but if I want to print a property of any of the objects like so:

```
{{#each products}}
{{this.title}}
{{/each}}
```

nothing shows up, literally nothing. no errors, no 'undefined' just nothing.

I'm pretty sure I'm getting the syntax inside {{this.title}} wrong but I'm not sure. I used this exact code in another project and it worked fine. I don't know what I am doing wrong here.

And for reference I console logged the array I passed in right before my res.render and it looked fine. Here's what the elements of the array look like(this is just the 1st element):

```
{
title: 'Samsung Galaxy S20 Ultra 1TB',
price: 1999.99,
description: 'Lorem ipsum dolor...',
quantity: 10,
category: 'Mobile',
bestSeller: false,
imgPath: '/public/images/products/galaxys20ultra.png',
}
```

Comment: Did you try this? {{#each products}}
{{title}}
{{/each}}

Comment: or check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22696886/how-to-iterate-over-array-of-objects-in-handlebars

Comment: Yes I did and that didn't work but it's fine I just figured out that a recent update of express-handlebars disabled access of properties of objects by default. https://handlebarsjs.com/api-reference/runtime-options.html#options-to-control-prototype-access

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. A recent update of express-handlebars disabled access of properties from objects by default. You need to re-enable it in your app.engine function.

https://handlebarsjs.com/api-reference/runtime-options.html#options-to-control-prototype-access