# How to iterate trough nested object in handlebars

Tags: node.js, arrays, mongodb, object, handlebars.js

I've fetched my data from backend and displayed it in console. Everything is perfect but I couldn't display it out in handlebars.
here is my object,

how to render this data in handlebars

Comment: Where is your object?

Answer (score -1):

For iterating list of object [take a look that answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22697178)
This might be helpful for you.

[Instruction link](https://handlebarsjs.com/guide/#nested-input-objects)

```
{
    person: {
         police: {
             firstname: "Yehuda",
             lastname: "Katz",
        },
         army: {
             firstname: "Yehuda",
             lastname: "Katz",
        }
   },
}
```

Iterate the Object by following

```
{{person.police.firstname}} {{person.army.lastname}}
```

For Iteration over list of object follow

```
<ul class="people_list">
    {{#each people}}
         <li>{{this.name}} is {{this.age}} year old.</li>
   {{/each}}
</ul>
```

Where people is like

```
{
    people: [
        {name: "Yehuda Katz", age: 22},
        {name: "Alan Johnson", age: 32},
        {name: "Charles Jolley", age: 45},
    ],
}
```